# Embed is very short length compared with other bots

Tags: discord, embed

I want to have a very simple command where i make a command and add details with paragraphs.
The output handled by the bot is very weird. I have similar commands with bots from carl bot but in my personal bot it doesnt work.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
let config = require('../config.json');
module.exports = {
    name: 'cm',
    description: 'Comando',
    execute(message, args){
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#47e10c")
        .setDescription(args)
        .setFooter(`${config.SERVER_LOGO}`)
        message.channel
        .send(embed)
    }
}
```

It stays like this
[Post in discord](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCi3p.png)

Comment: Simply 'does not work' is not enough for us to understand how to help, I request you to edit it with errors you are facing, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you defined `args`, we generally define them as

```js
const prefix = "!";
const args = <message>.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
```

And they return an array of arguments for suppose

```js
// !command hello there would return:
args = ["hello",'there"];
```

Now to set them as your description in MessageEmbed, you have to join them as a string, you may use `array.join()` method for the same, so you may do something like this:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require ("discord.js");
message.channel.send(new MessageEmbed().setDescription(args.join(" ")));
```

Comment: My index has that and it only works when i make (message) the args const doesnt work.

Comment: `client.on('message', message =>{
  if(!message.content.startsWith(PREFIX) || message.author.bot) return
  const args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(!client.commands.has(command)) return
  try {
    client.commands.get(command).execute(message,args);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

  if (command === 'bilhete') {
        client.commands.get('bilhete').execute(message, args, Discord, client);
    }

});`